# Are non Muslims allowed to pray Congregational Salat in Mosques

Tags: salat, sharia, non-muslim

Non Muslims have asked me to pray salat in Mosques , for the purpose of Dawah I really took the person to Mosque and showed him how to pray and he joined the congregational prayer, Is this correct to do for dawah purpose ? or how to deal if the non muslim wants to get an experience of Salat in congregation ? Also doing so, does it affect the salat of other members in the prayer?

(The non Muslim did like the experience though)

Answer (score -1):

Assalam-O-Alaykoum Brother

I would like to thank you about this generosity in spreading Islam in such innovative ways, but we have strict rules in concerning worshiping established by Allah and they never could never been changed by anyone rather than Allah, so, please note that The Islam is a requirements for the validity of Salah, by attaching people to Islam by the way described above, you're setting new rules over Allah rules by eliminating the Islam requirement in Salah rules, and this is an error.

And Allah knows better.

Comment: walekum assalaam. Obviously salat is not valid for him but just for the sake of experience as asked

Comment: @UmarAdeel dear brother, i guess you miss understood my point, Salah and it's rules are given by Allah, ok, one of Salah requirements is Islam, by attaching people to Islam by the way described above, you're setting new rules over Allah rules by eliminating the Rukun of Islam, have you get my point brooo !

Comment: yes bro i got it, please explain this clearly in the answer

Comment: anyways many non muslims like salah, and want to perform salah without converting to Islam. I guess they can be asked to pray seperately?

Comment: I have not given the DV though

Comment: i have improved the formatting bro, i suggest to tell him to enter to Islam and pray as they want in case of rejecting Islam and it's rules and rituals they could quit when they want to ... and Allah knows better.

Comment: if you like the response accept it as response, otherwise may Allah give as the right science and facts ... regards